# How to get Apache to run the PHP installed by brew

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, httpd.conf

I am using this guide to get php running now that I've updated to Catalina:
https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions
I got all the way to the PHP portion and things went sideways. I used

```
$ brew install php@7.3
$ brew install php@7.4
```

and the installs went fine but when I ran

```
php -v
```

I got what must be some old install:

```
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2020 19:14:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

When I run

```
which php
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/php
```

Which is definitely not the right one. In my httpd.conf I have it pointing to the one given to me by brew like this:

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

I also have all the other requisites (afaik) like these in my httpd.conf as well:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

When I add the info.php file like the guide says and go to http://localhost/info.php I just get the plain text "echo " ~/Sites/info.php" and not the actual PHP info page so I know it's not working. Any idea how I can get it to use the right PHP? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!